# Importing CSV into Rstudio - column header disappears

Tags: r, excel, rstudio

I'm having trouble intermittently losing column headers when I try to import an Excel sheet into RStudio. It will end up looking something like this (there should be three column headers where the red arrow is):

[image]

I've tried copy-pasting the whole table into a new worksheet, and each time I do that, I sometimes lose another column header, so I know it's not the way I've formatted my Excel sheet. This always happens to the last few columns.

When I try older versions of the table, it turns out OK, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Anyone have any ideas? It's quite frustrating.

Comment: No idea unless you show more information, for example what the original file looks like, what R command you are using to import the file, and what the object looks like in R.

Comment: Sorry! It's `read_excel` from the `readxl` package. On Rstudio this choice of code is by default when an Excel sheet is imported

Comment: Your problems are not reproducible. Suggest upgrading to the latest RStudio and installing the latest readxl package. Apart from that, there's not much else anyone can advise.

Answer (score 0):

What package/function you are using to import the data? And to confirm, is the file type a .csv, .xlsx, or something else?

If it is an Excel file and you are using {readxl}, you can specify the column names at import:

```r
library(readxl)

read_excel(
  readxl_example("datasets.xlsx"), sheet = "chickwts",
  col_names = c("chick_weight", "chick_ate_this"), skip = 1
)
```

Comment: Hi! I'm using the latest Rstudio, and there's a way to automatically import Excel sheets using the `readxl` package, and `read_excel` function. The file type is .xlsx Funny thing is, if I reduce the number of columns (I currently have over 30), this fixes the problem. I'm not sure if `readxl` has a problem with reading over a specified number of columns, that would seem unusual...

Comment: I would suggest you try a couple of alternatives to see if the problem goes away.
Ex: (i) use the `read.xlsx()` function or the `read.xlsx2()` function of the same `readxl` package to see if the problem persists; (ii) use another package to read Excel files (e.g. `XLConnect` -> `readTable()` function; (iii) take a look at the `.name_repair` parameter in the `read_excel()` function, whose description starts as: "Handling of column names. By default, readxl ensures column names are not empty and are unique."
Also, it would help if you post the names of the columns in your Excel file.